# How can I get a consistent result from gethostname() on OS X?

Tags: macos, router

When I call gethostname() on my Mac, sometimes it returns "george", sometimes it returns "George.local". What can I change so that it will always return the same thing? (I don't care which; I just want it to be consistent.)

Background: I use Unison (www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html) on my Mac running 10.6. Unison uses a combination of things, one of which is the host name, to name the file in which it keeps previous results. When the string returned from gethostname() changes, Unison can't find the previous file. This results in a variety of unpleasant behaviors.

When I originally configured the system, I set the name in the Sharing control panel to "George". Currently when I use the hostname command, it returns "george". When I used Unison a few days ago, Unison used the name "George.local". I've seen this behavior with Unison several times over the past few months.

I've changed a lot of things between these times; I have no idea which, if any, might be significant.

1) I'm doing this from my laptop. At various times, it's connected to different routers and sometimes not connected at all.

2) I may have upgraded versions of OS X between times. For the current issue, I'm sure I did upgrade (from 10.6.6 to 10.6.7). For previous occurrences, I don't remember.

3) Sometimes I connect using Airport, sometimes with a cable.

Can anyone shed any light on what gethostname() might be doing and why it might return different strings?

Thanks, Pat

(Update 1 May 2011) The issue seems to be a bad interaction between OS X and the 2Wire router for my AT&T DSL service. When I boot without connecting to the network, hostname returns "George.local", which is what I've set in the Sharing control panel. Once I connect to the router, using either Ethernet or AirPort, hostname now returns "george".

Is there some configuration option in that specific router that controls this?

This didn't happen either with my Verizon FIOS router or with my Verizon DSL. I don't remember the brands of those routers, but neither was a 2Wire.

Comment: It looks like your updated question is more of a http://superuser.com or http://apple.stackexchange.com question now. It could be the case that the router has a DHCP server that sends a hostname.

Answer (score 0):

How about I offer a different alternative instead?  gethostbyname() is actually an older API and actually isn't the current recommended API to use.  The current recommended API to use, that has been standardized and exists pretty much everywhere, is getaddrinfo().  You should consider switching to that instead!

Comment: Hi Wes. To clarify something, you said that "gethostbyname" is not recommended. Unison uses "gethostname", which is part of the POSIX library. So, unless I've misunderstood something, this suggestion doesn't actually apply to the current situation. Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't exist and won't be around for a long time.  But, it's not portable (cause not everything is POSIX compliant) and getaddrinfo was designed to deal with multiple things in a better way (like IPv6 addresses).  It's defined in RFC 3493 and is consistently implemented everywhere.  Now...  I'll say it again, though: you **can** still use gethostbyname()

Comment: gethostname vs. gethost_by_name. Two different calls. That's what I was questioning.